# How to add a progress bar when playing a remote mp3

Tags: ios, audio, titanium

I am playing a remote mp3 audio file , i just want to add a progress bar and a label to show that how much time is remaining .

How can i do that .
I am using the following code to play the remote mp3 file.

The link for my code is here !!!

http://pastie.org/3613911

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

If you want to show progress bar then you need total duration of your mp3 file. But with current Titanium 1.8 SDK you can not get **total** duration from **audio player** of your remote file (.mp3). But still, you can get total duration from backend side. Like, set total duration tag in your response and use it in **progress**'s maximum size .

```
//assing total duration in milliseconds and divide by 1000 from your server

var totalDurationFromBackend = 898 // its in your case.Also divided by 1000 

var audioPlayer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({ 

    url: 'http://naturallyimprove.com/mp3/Drone.mp3',
    allowBackground: true
});

var pb=Titanium.UI.createProgressBar
({
   top:10,
   width:250,
   height:'auto',
   min:0,
   max:totalDurationFromBackend,
   value:0,
   color:'#fff',
   style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.ProgressBarStyle.PLAIN,
});
win.add(pb);
pb.show();

audioPlayer.addEventListener('progress',function(e) 
{
   Ti.API.info('Time Played: ' + Math.round(e.progress) + ' milliseconds');

   // set the progress bar's progress value with current time played.. (milliseconds) 
   pb.value =  Math.round(e.progress/1000) ; 
});

startStopButton.addEventListener('click',function() {

// When paused, playing returns false.
// If both are false, playback is stopped.
if (audioPlayer.playing || audioPlayer.paused)
{
    audioPlayer.stop();
    pauseResumeButton.enabled = false;
    if (Ti.Platform.name === 'android')
    { 
        audioPlayer.release();
    }   
}
else
{
    audioPlayer.start();
    pauseResumeButton.enabled = true;
}
 });
```

**Also another Alternative is** : Use [`Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer`](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer-object) pass the url to it and you will get duration from video player of your remote file(.mp3 too) and use it in Audio player...

Comment: `var audioPlayer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({ 
    url: 'http://naturallyimprove.com/mp3/Drone.mp3',
    allowBackground: true
});`

Can you give example using the above created audio !!!